# Ubuntu 11.04: Running MARS simulator

Tags: java, ubuntu, mars-simulator

I am trying to run the MARS simulator in order to do some Assembly homework in Ubutnu 11.04. MARS(jar file) requires Java to be installed and so I did install Java.

After that I typed

```
java -jar .jar
```

and as a result I got:

> Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from .jar

What must I do in order to run this file properly?

Comment: Do you mean the [MIPS Assembly and Runtime Simulator](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/) from Missouri State?

Comment: `java -jar .jar` isn't a valid command, as you haven't told it which jar file to run.  It should be something like `java -jar jarname.jar`. Please read the [faq] and [ask] to understand the guidelines for posting on SO.

Comment: i fixed this but now when i type it correct terminal shows            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at java.io.File.normalizePath(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.io.File.<init>(libgcj.so.10)
   at mars.util.FilenameFinder.getFilenameList(FilenameFinder.java:110)
   at mars.mips.instructions.SyscallLoader.loadSyscalls(SyscallLoader.java:63)
   at mars.mips.instructions.InstructionSet.populate(InstructionSet.java:3066)
   at mars.Globals.initialize(Globals.java:125)
   at mars.MarsLaunch.<init>(MarsLaunch.java:125)
   at Mars.main(Mars.java:39)

Comment: Please update the original post; do not put a stacktrace in a comment.

Comment: It now looks like you are missing one or more required files that the simulator needs (loadSyscalls?)

Answer (score 0):

There are different Java implementations and you are not using the "official" one. (As is clear from the `libgcj.so` that appears on your error) and that one tends to be the most reliable.

Ubuntu 11.04 might still have the `java-6-sun` package (it was deprecated on newer Ubuntu releases because of license conflicts), so you should try with that one.

If that java is not in Ubuntu, then you can try downloading and installing Java from [the Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre-6u31-download-1501637.html).